# have a UINavigationBar title for each page in PageViewController

Tags: swift

I have set up my pageViewController (embedded in a NavigationController) with an array of ViewControllers to use as the pages (seen below):

```
`
class PageViewController: UIPageViewController {

    var arrayIndex: Int = 0
    var navigationBar = UINavigationBar()
    var pageControl = UIPageControl.self





    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        dataSource = self



        if let firstViewController = orderedViewControllers.first {
            setViewControllers([firstViewController],
                               direction: .Forward,
                               animated: true,
                               completion: nil)
        }




    }


    // set up & order all view controllers

    private(set) lazy var orderedViewControllers: [UIViewController] = {
        return [self.newDayViewController("monday"),
                self.newDayViewController("tuesday"),
                self.newDayViewController("wednesday"),
                self.newDayViewController("thursday")//,
                self.newDayViewController("friday"),
                self.newDayViewController("saturday"),
                self.newDayViewController("sunday")
        ]


    }()






    // instantiate view controllers above that contain 'day' (easiest method to differentiate from other controllers)

    private func newDayViewController(day: String) -> UIViewController {
        return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) .
            instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("\(day)")
    }


    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
        if (!completed) {
            return
        }

         arrayIndex =  Int(pageViewController.viewControllers!.first!.view.restorationIdentifier!)!


        switch arrayIndex {

        case 0:
            navigationBar.topItem!.title = "Monday"
            break

        case 1:
            navigationBar.topItem!.title = "Tuesday"
            break

        case 2:
            navigationBar.topItem!.title = "Wednesday"
            break

        case 3:
            navigationBar.topItem!.title = "Thursday"
        default:
            navigationBar.topItem!.title = "Timetable"


        }
    }








}


extension PageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {




    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.indexOf(viewController) else {
            return nil
        }



        let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1


        guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
            return orderedViewControllers.last
        }

        guard orderedViewControllers.count > previousIndex else {
            return nil
        }

        return orderedViewControllers[previousIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
                            viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.indexOf(viewController) else {
            return nil
        }

        let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1
        let orderedViewControllersCount = orderedViewControllers.count




        //MARK: - determine which viewController the user is on



        guard orderedViewControllersCount != nextIndex else {
            return orderedViewControllers.first
        }

        guard orderedViewControllersCount > nextIndex else {
            return nil
        }

        return orderedViewControllers[nextIndex]
    }

    func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return orderedViewControllers.count
    }

    func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        guard let firstViewController = viewControllers?.first,
            firstViewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.indexOf(firstViewController) else {
                return 0
        }

        return firstViewControllerIndex
    }


}

`
```

I am wondering how I could have it so that when the user is swiping through the pageViews, the UINavigationBar's title changes to the title of the view they are looking at ? e.g : When the user is looking at the mondayViewController, the title is monday and they can swipe to tuesday and the title will change etc.

Any suggestions are welcome

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some errors in your code, first of all there isnt a `UIPageViewControllerDelegate`, so the delegates method will never be called.

Then, I dont know if your `PageViewController` really have a `UINavigationController`. To ensure that you can embed it by selecting your `PageViewController` and make the same thing as maded in picture:

[image]

so you can see in your storyboard both `UINavigationController` and `UIPageViewController` like this:

[image]

After you have all your day `UIViewController` created with each storyboard id, for example for monday:

[image]

you can modify you code like the code below:

```
   import UIKit
    class PageViewController: UIPageViewController,UIPageViewControllerDelegate {
        var arrayIndex: Int = 0
        var pageControl = UIPageControl.self
        private(set) lazy var orderedViewControllers: [UIViewController] = {
            return [self.newDayViewController("monday"),
                    self.newDayViewController("tuesday"),
                    self.newDayViewController("wednesday"),
                    self.newDayViewController("thursday"),
                    self.newDayViewController("friday"),
                    self.newDayViewController("saturday"),
                    self.newDayViewController("sunday")
            ]
        }()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            dataSource = self
            delegate = self
            if let firstViewController = orderedViewControllers.first {
                self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "monday"
                setViewControllers([firstViewController],
                                   direction: .Forward,
                                   animated: true,
                                   completion: nil)
            }
        }

        private func newDayViewController(day: String) -> UIViewController {
            return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) .
                instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("\(day)")
        }

        func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
            if (!completed) {
                return
            }

            if let firstViewController = viewControllers?.first,
                let arrayIndex = orderedViewControllers.indexOf(firstViewController) {
                switch arrayIndex {
                case 0:
                    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "Monday"
                    break

                case 1:
                     self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "Tuesday"
                    break

                case 2:
                     self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "Wednesday"
                    break

                case 3:
                     self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "Thursday"
                default:
                     self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "Timetable"


                }
            }
        }
    }
    extension PageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
        func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
            guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.indexOf(viewController) else {
                return nil
            }
            let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1
            guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
                return orderedViewControllers.last
            }
            guard orderedViewControllers.count > previousIndex else {
                return nil
            }
            return orderedViewControllers[previousIndex]
        }

        func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
                                viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
            guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.indexOf(viewController) else {
                return nil
            }
            let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1
            let orderedViewControllersCount = orderedViewControllers.count
            //MARK: - determine which viewController the user is o
            guard orderedViewControllersCount != nextIndex else {
                return orderedViewControllers.first
            }
            guard orderedViewControllersCount > nextIndex else {
                return nil
            }
            return orderedViewControllers[nextIndex]
        }
        func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
            return orderedViewControllers.count
        }
        func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
            guard let firstViewController = viewControllers?.first,
                firstViewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.indexOf(firstViewController) else {
                    return 0
            }
            return firstViewControllerIndex
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you so much Alessandro !

Comment: done! I can't rate it because I am new on the forum and don't have the rep points